# def() function screws with my indentation

Tags: python

I'm writing a basic script that scans files and moves them if they fit some criteria set by the user.

I have tried complying with what it wants but that just ends up with every line of code being indented one more than the other.

```
def check():
    #code simplication
    for i in range(2):
        if fileScanDestination == '':
            noValue(moveFrom)
        else:
            #exits

        if fileMoveDestination == '':
            noValue(moveTo)
        else:
            #exits

        if specialFileExtension == '':
            str(specialFileExtension) == 'nil'
        else:
            #exits

        if fileNameSpecial == '':
            str(fileNameSpecial) == str('nil')
        else:
            #exits

def p(text):
    print(text)

#setting up tkinter


# getting variable data

p('Please enter the path for the files you would like to sort.')
fileScanDestination == str(input())
```

This should just have to be indented once, then exit. But since it wants to indent every new line, which just looks bad.

Comment: Comments don't count as statements, `pass` is how you write "do nothing" in python.

Comment: What do you mean by "complying with what it wants"? Who is "it", and what exactly does it say it "wants"?

Comment: Or you could just remove the `else:` of course - it's optional, you know.

Comment: Does `#exits` mean exit the loop, or return from the function?

Comment: Do you maybe want to use `elif` instead? It is a bit hard to understand exactly what is your goal here.

Comment: @JackHolman if you could mark an answer it would help other users acknowledge the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting some `pass` instructions after the `else` statements, or some `return`'s if you say it should exit.

You could even shorten the whole thing by doing:

```
if any([
    fileScanDestination == '',
    fileMoveDestination == '',
    specialFileExtension == '',
    str(specialFileExtension) == 'nil',
    str(fileNameSpecial) == str('nil'),
    fileNameSpecial == ''
]):
    return
```